Flame for the thumb
This movie I saw back in 90's or maybe end of 80's. 
There was a boy with I think super natural powers and here a man with him I think I help that boy to read some place. The only scene I remember was the man flicked his thumb and then flame came out of the thumb and he looked at the boy and smiled.
I don't remember if the boy had supernatural powers or the man.

7 Faces of Dr. Lao (1964)?
Dr. Lao lights his pipe with his thumb.
(about 10 seconds in)




There is also this guy from "Fire", a 1st season episode of the X-Files:


That's funny ... imdb has the show listed as "1964", yet the copyright at the beginning of the trailer (0:17 seconds in) shows it as 1963 (MCMLXIII). Sometimes I wish I'd never learned how to read Roman numerals, lol.

Sheriff and the Satellite Kid.

A young humanoid alien who gets stranded on earth hooks up with a grizzled old sheriff in a western town and tries to help him solve a tough case, but the sheriff doesn't want any help from a "kid."

Bud Spencer flicks his thumb at some point and it's ignited, to Bud's surprise and the kid's delight.



I LOVED that movie growing up!

+1, I'm sure THIS is it. I loved that movies as a kid (there were at least two of them)

Second movie was: Why Did You Pick on Me? also known as Everything Happens to Me,
